# Image uploading in Mobile-Safari

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, mobile-safari

I'm building a JQuery Mobile application using Ruby on Rails and I need a way to upload photos from the mobile device to Amazon S3. I thought that the best way would be to use Paperclip gem, but the main problem is that in Safari (in case of IPhone) the file input is disabled.

Is there another solution?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MobileSafari doesn't allow for direct uploads (yet). It would be possible through an external app like [Picup](http://picupapp.com/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It's a pity that there is not a direct way to upload files via Safari. :-(

Another option for me would be to access the camera, take a picture and save it directly to my server. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Sorry, it would still only be possible via a third-party app like Picup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Apple will ever support a direct upload function in MobileSafari, since it's too complicated for them to give the end-user limited access to the filesystem to upload a file (whether it be from /var/mobile/) due to security reasons. Maybe an upload from another app like Dropbox or iDisk would do the trick, but that's just my guess.

Comment: not true anymore. You can upload pictures and video from the iPhone library with a input of type 'file'

Comment: @Alain..Can you please guide me for file upload in ios using HTML 5.?